# issues with preg_match PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string:

```
$str="(94896)content is here(/94896)(94897)content is here(/94897)(94898)content is here(/94898)(94899)content is here(/94899)";
```

the `(number)` and `(/number)` act as tags to take certain content out of the string.

and I have a `preg_match` to take the content out:

```
if(preg_match('/(94896)\"(.*)\"(\/94896)/',$str,$c)) {echo "I found the content, its:".$co[1];}
```

Now for some reason, it doesn't find a match in the string (`$str`), though its clearly there....

Any ideas on what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the double-quotes out of your regex string, since they don't appear in $str, but are expected by the regex.

```
'/(94896)\"(.*)\"(\/94896)/'
//       ^^    ^^
//        These aren't in the string.
```

EDIT: I think you'll also need to escape your brackets, since they will be getting read as grouping operators, not actual brackets.

Your expression should be:

```
'/\(94896\)(.*)\(\/94896\)/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses are used in a regex to denote subpatterns. If you want to search these characters in a string, you must escape them:

```
preg_match('/\(94896\)(.*)\(\/94896\)/',$str,$c)
```

If the pattern is found:

```
echo "I found the content, its:".$c[0];
```

Oh, and as Karl Nicoll says, why are the quotations in your pattern?

Comment: double backslashes would make the engine look for a literal backslash in that position. A single backslash is all that's needed for escaping.

Comment: @MarcB - I hate PHP for that. It should either be a string with double backslashes, or slash delimited (like JavaScript or Ruby) with single backslashed, but PHP is a string with single backslashes. It keeps me up at night, it really does.

Answer (score 0):

To match all content:

```
$str="(94896)content is here(/94896)(94897)content is here(/94897)(94898)content is here(/94898)(94899)content is here(/94899)";

$re = '/\((\d+)\)(.*)\(\/\1\)/';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);
```

Number will be in `$matches[*][1]`, content in `$matches[*][2]`.